# AngularJS (Smart-Table): How to modify "skipNatural" boolean without changing smart-table.js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smart-table

I would like to change the "skipNatural" boolean that's part of the smart-table.js file. However, since I use Bower to update the module when required, I'm sure that when I do run the update, it will overwrite my boolean change. Here is how it looks in the Smart-Table file:

```
ng.module('smart-table')
  .constant('stConfig', {
    pagination: {
      template: 'template/smart-table/pagination.html',
      itemsByPage: 10,
      displayedPages: 5
    },
    search: {
      delay: 400, // ms
      inputEvent: 'input'
    },
    select: {
      mode: 'single',
      selectedClass: 'st-selected'
    },
    sort: {
      ascentClass: 'st-sort-ascent',
      descentClass: 'st-sort-descent',
      skipNatural: false,
      delay:300
    },
    pipe: {
      delay: 100 //ms
    }
  });
```

Is their a way to modify the boolean by perhaps either extending the Smart-Table constant, or running a Decorator? At the moment, I'm calling my smart-table.min.js file, and then using ocLazyLoad, I am calling other files.

Also, I have several tables used through out the site, and would like to toggle the Boolean at one point rather than set the value on several table headers to reduce redundancy

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the official documentation (it's in [Sort-data](http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-sort), and it's easy to miss)

> You can skip the "natural order" state by adding st-skip-natural="true" as attribute of your th element.

so just add the attribute to your `st-sort` like so

```
<th st-sort="birthDate" st-skip-natural="true">birth date</th>
```

**Edit:**

Refering to this [Issue](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/commit/f9b042f53598c8147e7f94500d259ce36d4d4d39) on GitHub, the author made skip-natural globally  configurable, you can override Smart Table's global properties in your application's `.config` section like so, so you wont have to touch any of the source files

```
angular.module('myModule', []).config(function(stConfig) {
  stConfig.sort.skipNatural = true;
});
```

The docs cover it under the **Global configuration** section,
the docs also provide a [list of defaults](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/blob/master/src/stConfig.js)

Comment: Sorry. I should have explained. I have several tables used through out the site, and would like to toggle the Boolean at one point rather than set the value on several table headers to reduce redundancy.

Comment: then change the `true` to some global application value using `.constant`, if you want to avoid writing `st-skip-natural="value"` altogether, then you can write a directive to wrap `st-sort`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the docs. I did go through them (that's how I got this far), but is there a way to edit this file and then when you update your Bower file, it stays the same? Perhaps I'm asking for too much. heh.

Comment: you edit `stConfig.sort.skipNatural = true;` in your application's `app.js` file, you don't need to edit anything else.

Comment: Your Edit was correct; it works perfectly. I just needed to understand that my angular.module already has the dependencies rendered in the app.js file and that I can summon "stConfig" easily from after the injection.